# Unable to show buttons in Hero Card and Tap Action not working for Hero Card in Microsoft BOT

Tags: javascript, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

We are working on Teams BOT application, where we have implemented logic to unfurl link to an adaptive card.
Below is the sample code for adaptive card generation:

```
composeExtension: {
            type: 'result',
            attachmentLayout: 'list',
            attachments: [{
                preview: CardFactory.heroCard("text1", "text2")
                ...CardFactory.adaptiveCard(card)
            }]
}
```

As it is mandatory to have a Preview card which is a Hero Card and an adaptive card as full card. We have added Hero Card with basic details like Title, Desc and logo.
Now I am updating this Hero Card as I want to open a custom link on click of the hero card. Also want to explore possibility of adding actions/buttons to hero card.
Below is the sample code for the same.

```
CardFactory.heroCard(
        'Title',
        'Description',
        CardFactory.images(['logoURL']),
        CardFactory.actions([
            {
                type: 'openUrl',
                title: 'openUrl',
                value: 'https://www.example.com'
            }]),
        { tap: { type: ActionTypes.OpenUrl, title: 'Tap', value: 'https://example.com '}}
    );
```

My expectation with the addition of Tap Action is that on click of the card, https://example.com should open in a new browser Tab.
But it does not open this link in a new tab on click of card.

Also I don't see any button/action added on hero card by the name "openURL" even after adding it to the actions list.

Any changes to title, description and logo are reflecting in the hero card, however adding actions/buttons or updating the link on tap action is not reflecting. Is there any additional change needed to support this.

Comment: If you want to add button/action added on hero card by the name "openURL", which is supported in adaptive card.but as you mention above to have a Preview card which is a Hero Card and an adaptive card as full card then on preview card this functionality is not possible to implement there.

Comment: You can refer the below sample -

1.https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/msgext-search/csharp

2.https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/msgext-link-unfurling/csharp

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT- So does it mean it is not possible to have actions when hero card is used as preview card? (We use hero card just like it is shared in above sample code)
Also when I use hero card as preview card, and If I want to open a custom link on tap of card interface, I was expecting that by adding this code : { tap: { type: ActionTypes.OpenUrl, title: 'Tap', value: 'https://example.com '}}
I would be able to open the mentioned link on tap of preview card.Is that possible?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT - Or If we use hero card as preview card, is there no way we can override the hyperlink that opens on click of hero card interface.

Comment: Yes. if you try to hyperlink on hero card preview then it is not possible.
Also, for reference please have look into this-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/msgext-action-preview/csharp